# Twitter Kit RestAPI does not support IPv6? - Rejected from Apple

Tags: ios, rest, twitter, twitterkit

My app is rejected due to not supporting IPv6 network support.

Here is message from Apple:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 11 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Submitting a Tweet through the app does not post it on the feed or on
>   the Twitter web-site.

My app is very simple and posts text using RestAPI call. Here is code snippet.

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userid)
let url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
let message:[String:Any] = ["status": text]
var error: NSError?
let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: url, parameters: message, error: &error)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
  client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, ConnectionError) -> Void in
    if let error = connectionError {
      print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(error)
      }
    } else {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(nil)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Did anyone experience this?

Comment: It may be nothing to do with IPv6, they are just telling you about the environment they tested in. Did you supply a test account for them to use?  Have you tested your app on a clean device or simulator where you aren't logged in to Twitter?  Have you tested in an IPv6 environment?

Comment: @Paulw11 I works well, but not tested on IPv6 environment. I am considering whether the api.twitter.com supports IPv6.

Comment: I have faced similar issue. The tester seemed to be in China where twitter isn't accessible and he sent me a screenshot of the Twitter login page where it said "Technical difficulty", not sure why he would sit in China and test a Twitter App. Also, I used Google Firebase which is also blocked in china and my app handled it correctly and showed them a proper error. They simply said that it's a IPv6 issue. Appeal it hard with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing AFNetworking from Podfile fixed the issue